# Create event for certain days in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to implement my PHP and MySQL knowledge.

I am about to create an auction page that only last for 3 days, and it will be closed afterwards,
I really dont have any idea how to achieve this feature

I have Auction table in MySQL with following columns:

-AuctionID

-AuctionName

-Image

-Description

-StartDate(timestamp datatype with current_timestamp)

-EndDate(date)

Have been trying to google it but cant find any..

Can anybody help me please?
Any attention given will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the filtering in your sql query

```
SELECT * FROM Auction a WHERE now() BETWEEN a.StartDate AND a.EndDate;
```

The query should return only auctions that are currently active. You can then display the list of auctions in your page.

```
$date = "Mar 03, 2011";
$Startdate = strtotime($date);
$Enddate = strtotime("+3 day", $Startdate);
echo date('M d, Y', $Enddate);
```

This should work

Comment: the startDate will be assigned automatically by current_timestamp
but the endDate will be inputed by the user itself. should I make it the endDate automatically assigned 3 days after the startDate? and if so, how to do so?? any guidance? thanks

Comment: This query is used to retrieve only auctions that are currently not closed. Will edit answer to include code to calculate endDate

Comment: Really appreciate your help sir! God bless you!

Comment: Sir how can I close the auction so there is nobody can access that certain auction page anymore? thanks

Comment: use the filter query above, it will display only active auctions, if an auction is closed it will not be displayed, nobody can click into the page since there is no link.

Comment: oh yes sir. I already get it. really appreciate your help Sir! You saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Sir, I am having a problem. my startingdate is using now() which will retrieve the current_timestamp, when I try to use following query: 
$startingDate = strtotime('now()');
$endDate = strtotime("+3 day", $startingDate);
echo date('M d, Y', $endDate);
the end date will end up 0000-00-00
the format of current timestamp is YYYY-MM-DD.. what should I do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save the creation date into the database table.
Run a cron job on the server, which will take the date from the database and compare it with today's date.

```
 If the difference of the days >= (greater or equal to) 3 close the auction
```

Running the cron jobs is not something hard, Lunix provides the facility via cron tabs and in windows you can do the same thing with a number of ways.

Comment: the creation date is the StartDate table right? do you have any idea how to close the auction? thanks

Comment: @Foster Yes, that is the StartDate column, once the difference is equal to or greater than 3 days, save that date in the mysql column EndDate and close the auction.

As far as the closing auction thing is concerned
View all those auctions which don't have any value in the EndDate Column

   **select * from tableName where EndDate is null or EndDate="" **
Based on the default value of EndDate you can modify the query, if you are keep NULL you can use that check else the check of ""

Answer (score -1):

Idea: You could use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

to get you PHP page to constantly check the status of an auction item.

Comment: thanks for the idea! I really appreciate it! Is there any help for my question? thanks! :)

Comment: This would require a browser window to be open constantly on your computer, and it would affect normal users too. There are many more acceptable programmatical solutions.

Comment: That is true, but it depends on whether you are intending to use ajax.